# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can someone help to fix this error in google colab

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
image = Image.open(root_path + 'DJI_0107.JPG')
data = np.array(image)
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0] * data.shape[1], data.shape[2])
mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)
data = mean
pca = PCA(0.95)
data_pca = pca.fit_transform(data)
data_inv = pca.inverse_transform(data_pca)
ata_inv = data_inv.reshape(image.size[1], image.size[0], data_inv.shape[1])
image_inv = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(data_inv))
image.show()
image_inv.show()
image_inv.save("gambar_diperbaiki.jpg")
```

error in google colab

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 16>()
14 # PCA dengan 95% varians dijelaskan
15 pca = PCA(0.95)
---> 16 data_pca = pca.fit_transform(data)
17 # inversi PCA untuk mendapatkan gambar yang diperbaiki
18 data_inv = pca.inverse_transform(data_pca)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
900             # If input is 1D raise error
901             if array.ndim == 1:
--> 902                 raise ValueError(
903                     "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
904                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[59.30950659 58.35990892 51.05735574].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Remove `data = mean`.